# Xamarin Forms XAML: yet another Binding syntax question

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

In my Xamarin Forms project I use the following code to provide mock data to xaml previewer at design time:

C#:

```
namespace MyApp.Data
{
    public class StaticData
    {
        private static AppMockData mockData;
        public static AppMockData MockData => mockData ?? (mockData = new MockData());

        public class MockData
        {
            public List<MyObj> LstObj { get; set; }
                = new List<MyObj>()
                {
                    new MyObj() { P1 = "V1", P2 = "V2" },
                    new MyObj() { P1 = "V1", P2 = "V2" },
                    new MyObj() { P1 = "V1", P2 = "V2" }
                };

            public MyObj SingleObj { get; set; } = new MyObj() { P1 = "V1", P2 = "V2" };
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:data="clr-namespace:MyApp.Data"
             BindingContext="{x:Static data:StaticData.MockData}"
             ... >  

<ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding LstObj}">
    ...
    <Label Text="{Binding P1}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding P2}" />
    ...
</ListView>
```

Then, at runtime:

```
var actualListData = GetDataFromDB(); // obj returned is of type List<MyObj>
MyList.ItemsSource = actualListData;
```

This is working fine.

I would like to do the same thing with SingleObj, that is, a single object, and not a list.
I tried something like:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:data="clr-namespace:MyApp.Data"
             BindingContext="{x:Static data:StaticData.MockData.SingleObj}"
             ... >

<Label Text="{Binding P1}" />
<Label Text="{Binding P2}" />
```

and in code behind:

```
var actualObj = GetDataFromDB(); // obj returned is of type MyObj
this.BindingSource = actualObj;
```

This works at runtime, but it doesn't at design time: "`{x:Static data:StaticData.MockData.SingleObj}`" is not recognized as a valid expression.

The only way I could make it work both at design time and at runtime is:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:data="clr-namespace:MyApp.Data"
             BindingContext="{x:Static data:StaticData.MockData}"
             ... >

<StackLayout x:Name="MyStackLayout" BindingContext="{Binding SingleObj}">
    <Label Text="{Binding P1}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding P2}" />
</StackLayout>
```

and:

```
var actualObj = GetDataFromDB(); // obj returned is of type MyObj
MyStackLayout.BindingContext = actualObj;
```

This way I have a StackLayout (used only for binding purposes) whose BindingContext is a property of MockData at design time, and the actual object at runtime.

I wonder if there is a syntax to specify SingleObj directly in ContentPage BindingContext, thus avoiding to put everything in a container layout.

Comment: Hi , have you solved it ? The ViewModel will be different effects between design time and runtime .Typically, the runtime performance is better .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics

Answer (score 0):

add `SingleObj` to your binding path expression

```
<ContentPage xmlns:data="clr-namespace:MyApp.Data"
             BindingContext="{x:Static data:StaticData.ViewModel}"
             ... >

<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding SingleObj.P1}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding SingleObj.P2}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: This would work at design time, but how can I code it to show live data at runtime? With StackLayout I do "var actualObj = GetDataFromDB(); MyStackLayout.BindingSource = actualObj;". This is not possible with your approach...

Comment: Don't assign a BindingContext to your StackLayout, just let it inherit the page's context and everything should work.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how would you set actual source at runtime...

Comment: `this.BindingContext = new DataViewModel();`

Comment: I understand that my explanation of how my code works was not so clear. I rewrote the question, hoping to be clearer

Comment: I think your problem is that you are using a single VM at design time, but not at runtime.  If you would use the same approach for both your problem would go away.  What are you NOT using a VM for runtime binding?